# Company Leased Car - Transfer from a colleague

Tags: india, car, transfer, auto-leasing

An employee in my org got a company leased car and he is planning to transfer the lease.

> EMI: Rs. 15300
>       Tenure: 60 months
>       Already paid 25 EMIs = Rs. 382500
>       Remaining 35 EMIs (that I'll need to pay) = Rs. 535500
>       Cash settlement he expects (buyer to pay) = Rs. 70000 (Against Rs. 382500 he has already paid)
>       Age of car: 2 years

Current on-road price of the same car and model (brand new) is arrpoximately `Rs. 850000`.

Is it advisable to go for this? I feel this is a good deal. Am i correct?

What else should i be careful about when going for this? I could think of these that i might need to check `Insurance, Accident History, Last maintenance done, Pending Tickets`. Anything else i should be worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Current on-road price of the same car and model (brand new) is approximately Rs. 850000.

This does not help. Find the equivalent used car value in market. The on-road price usually has insurance and registration fees. Reducing that and using a standard depreciation,
I guess the price would be around Rs. 600,000 to Rs 650,000. 
You are getting from your friend at Rs 600,000 ... less of interest payments to get like for like comparison should be around Rs 500,000.

Still a slightly good deal.

> What else should i be careful about when going for this?

What are the company lease terms, i.e. at the end of period do you have to pay something to company to get the car?